# List and download azure Blob storage files in python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I am following a tutorial where files are downloaded into databricks environment using `dbutils`. I'd like to do the same outside databricks.

How can I adapt the `download_dataset` function to work locally? There are no other credentials defined in any envvar that I can see, only the URI is avaiable at `wasbs://course-resources@dalhussein.blob.core.windows.net/datasets/bookstore/v1/`.

```
import os

import requests
import pandas as pd

def download_dataset(source, target):
    files = dbutils.fs.ls(source)

    for f in files:
        source_path = f"{source}/{f.name}"
        target_path = f"{target}/{f.name}"
        if not path_exists(target_path):
            print(f"Copying {f.name} ...")
            dbutils.fs.cp(source_path, target_path, True)


data_source_uri = "wasbs://course-resources@dalhussein.blob.core.windows.net/datasets/bookstore/v1/"
dataset_bookstore = 'dbfs:/mnt/demo-datasets/bookstore'
spark.conf.set(f"dataset.bookstore", dataset_bookstore)

download_dataset(data_source_uri, dataset_bookstore)
```

Tried with `response = requests.get(data_source_uri)`

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'wasbs://course-resources@dalhussein.blob.core.windows.net/datasets/bookstore/v1/'
```

and of course `dbutils` isn't available outside databricks

Comment: you have any access keys or credentials for storage account?

Comment: No, I don't... far as I can see `dbutils` seems to manage the downloads without them

Comment: without having credentials you can not access data outside of databricks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can list down storage account files using `dbutils.fs.ls` then credentials is configured in any one of the ways.

1. **OAuth 2.0 with an Azure service principal**
2. **Shared access signatures (SAS)**
3. **Account keys**

You can use option 2 and 3 to copy files locally.

To get credentials use below code.

```
sas_token = spark.conf.get("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net")
account_key = spark.conf.get("fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net")
```

You can use below function with any one of the above credentials.

First, install the required packages.

```
pip install fsspec adlfs
```

Next, create function as below.

```
import fsspec
import os

def download_dataset(src_dir_path,target,acc_cred):
    fs = fsspec.filesystem(protocol="az",account_name="<storage-account>",cred=acc_cred)
    for i in fs.glob(src_dir_path):
        print(i)
        fs.download(i,target)
```

and call this function passing `source`,`target` and `sas_token or account_key`.

Below is the file in my storage account.

[image]

Output using `account_key`

[image]

Output using `sas_token`

[image]

Make sure you change the argument name properly while getting filesystem object.